# php convert array values and combine into one when finding key words

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, replace, preg-match, str-replace

Im looking for the best way to do the following:

```
 [key] => Array
    (
        [alert] => Array
            (
                [0] => Possible text issue
                [1] => Multiple text issues
                [2] => Incorrect format
                [3] => format is not supported
            )
    )
```

I basically want to look for the keyword text in all the values and whichever one has text remove them and instead create a new value of "There are text issues"

and same thing with format where it would remove the last two values and create one saying "wrong format is used"

So my final array would look like so

```
 [key] => Array
    (
        [alert] => Array
            (
                [0] => There are text issues
                [1] => Wrong format is used
            )
    )
```

Any ideas on how this can be done. I would write what i have done so far but i dont even know where to start.

I am thinking for doing

```
 foreacch ($array['key']['alert'] as $key=>$value) {
      // maybe use preg_match for specific key words or use str_replace ??
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a recursive function, which goes through the whole array and subarrays, and searches for $contains string within the non-array values, and replaces the whole array element with the $stringToReplaceWith string.

```
function replaceArrayElementRecursiveley ($array, $contains = "text", $stringToReplaceWith = "There are text issues") {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = replaceArrayElementRecursiveley($value, $contains, $stringToReplaceWith);
        } else if (stripos($value, $contains) !== false) {
            $array[$key] = $stringToReplaceWith;
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

$test = array(
    "key" => array(
        "alert" => array(
            0 => "Possible text issues",
            1 => "Multiple text issues",
            2 => "Incorrect format",
            3 => "format is not supported",
        )
    )
);

$test = replaceArrayElementRecursiveley($test);
```

If you just need to search for "text" and nothing else in addition, then using a preg_replace is unnecessary in my opinion and so is preg_match in this case.
However, if you need to search for more then just one occurrence, you could easily switch the stripos() to preg_match().

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
foreach ($key['alert'] as $var1=>$var2)
{
     if(strstr($var2,'text'))
     {
         array_splice($var2,$var1,($var1)+1,'There are text issues');
     }
}

$Key['alert']=array_unique($Key['alert'])
```

But if the last array is NOT associative There is even a simpler way to work things out.